# Building Windows Clusters

Tags: windows-cluster, hpc

I'm a research student and I want to build a windows cluster at home with my laptops to test my parallel codes.

The problem is I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium, not a server edition.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and I installed Microsoft HPC Packs with SP1 and able to simulate MPI codes at my localhost without a problem. Now I want to see the real application.

I have 3 other laptops at home and Windows 7 Starter is installed on them. They don't have Visual Studio installed because I have only 1 license from the university.

So is there any way to build a Windows cluster with these configurations??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hardware is not fine for build a Microsoft cluster.
I suggest you to install VMware Server on your Windows 7 fastest laptop and build a virtual cluster. 
You will need also Windows Server 2003/2008 Enterprise Edition to install the cluster nodes.

Comment: so I must obtain Windows Server Enterprise edition. Enterprise edition is not available to students from my university, would standard edition work?

Comment: Sorry Standard Edition does not support clustering.

Comment: @Emre as mentioned you will need Enterprise. If you look into getting access to Dreamspark (and it is very simple) you will get an MSDN account with access to every server OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a student you should be able to sign up fro [Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx). This will give you an MSDN licence which will allow you to download and use any MS OS for testing and development purposes, which should apply here.

Comment: so you say that i need to download windows server, install it then build cluster, right?

Answer (score 0):

If Windows isn't a strict requirement, a Linux Live CD with cluster support, such as [PelicanHPC](http://pelicanhpc.org/) may work out.

Comment: it seems like i have to do it in that way - using linux. But I had a dream that using my laptop I could use any windows computer around to execute my code. but it seems impossible for now without server enterprise. Will try linux..